# Log-in user to his database using php to mysql via phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I need to log-in using phpMyAdmin my user to MySQL server.

I have my control panel, and i want put button "log into MySQL server as user1, user2, user3", when user click, it should open phpMyAdmin credits logged as user1, etc.

I can generate via PHP form, with POST field, contain MySQL login data (password, login), and send to phpMyAdmin login file, but it's too dangerous.

I'm looking for any other way. Does someone have idea ?

I can put phpMyAdmin, in same domain that my PHP script, maybe I( can authorize user via cookie? (generate cookie for phpMyAdmin with my PHP script).

Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: "I can generate via PHP form, with POST field, contain MySQL login data (password, login), and send to phpMyAdmin login file, but it's too dangerous." Why is this too dangerous? It's a page that auto-logs-in a user to a live MySQL database. They'll have the ability to delete everything either way.

Comment: Ok, so i will use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I found perfect sollution.

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types#signon

This work just like i want.